# Get location from google map in own app android

Tags: android, google-maps

I have an option in my project i.e. when I click to an icon it should open the google map(Which is done).
Now i need to get the user edited location,it means after the map is open if a user drag the marker and set it to a random position,i need to get the address of that position which is set by the user and set the address to a textview.
As we can see any app that supports add location option.

Can any one provide some sample code for this???Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can find anything from google api. you can find address from geocode api from link https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=-33.8670522,151.195736&result_type=street_address&key=yourkeyhere

key is: "Key for browser applications" which u register on google console.
when u request to geocode api, it responce json with address, from that parse json to get address. 
more referency [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#geocoding)